# how to switch user to run a command through shell script?

Tags: linux

I want to start stop db2 using shell script.  I want a script to login as db2inst1 user then run command /home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start.

I have tried using the below code but it doesnt work. please let me know whats wrong ?

```
 su - db2inst1 &&
/home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "-c" flag of su. For example:

```
su - db2inst1 -c "/home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start"
```